# Building C++ project using build-appveyor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, osmium

I do not know `C++`, but I need to build C++ application - [Osmium tool](https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool). I have not known that it is really hard to build C++ programs.  What I want is just create `.exe` file to merge maps. That is my simple goal.

[So docs says](https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool#Building):

> On Windows you can compile with the Visual Studio C++ compiler and nmake. The necessary dependencies can be installed with conda. See **appveyor.yml** for the necessary commands to compile osmium-tool.

**appveyor.yml** docs says:

> environment: matrix:
>     - config: Debug
>     - config: Release
>
> shallow_clone: true
>
> **Operating system (build VM template) os: Visual Studio 2015**
>
> platform: x64
>
> **scripts that are called at very beginning, before repo cloning init:**
>
> **clone directory clone_folder: c:\projects\osmium-tool**
>
> install:
>     - cd c:\projects
>     - git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium
>     - git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mapbox/protozero
>
> build_script:
>     - cd c:\projects/osmium-tool
>     - build-appveyor.bat

I've done all the above steps and now I'm trying to run in Windows 10:

```
build-appveyor.bat
```

However,I see the error:

```
System cannot find the path specified
```

An image:
[image]

Guys what am I doing wrong? Please, help me! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have VS C++ and nmake installed? Does typing `nmake` on the command line give an error?

Comment: yeah, I've intstalled C++ and according to the [docs - NMAKE is included when you install Visual Studio or the Visual C++](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dd9y37ha(v=vs.99))

Comment: But is the environment set up so you can run `nmake` from the command line? If you can't do that yourself, the script isn't going to be able to either. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019

Comment: @pcarter I'm sorry for the dumb question. however, what command should I run to test?

Comment: Just type `nmake` on the command line, if you get _'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file._ your environment isn't set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got osmium to compile for Windows after a bit of trial of error and research (wasn't very familiar with c++ when I started). Here are my notes -

Download and install prebuilt 64-bit boost

```
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.63.0/boost_1_63_0-msvc-14.0-64.exe
```

In C:\projects

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mapbox/protozero
git clone https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool
    - Checkout latest osmium-tool tag
```

VS2019

```
- Install desktop development with c++
- Install MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)

build-appveyor.bat
- Update vcvarsall.bat location for VS2019 install location (VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat)
- Changed cmake_cmd "Visual Studio 14 Win64" to "Visual Studio 16"
- Changed toolsversion from 14.0 to Current
- ensure DBOOST_ROOT path matches installed path of DBOOST e.g.  C:/local/boost_1_63_0
```

VS2015 community edition

```
Download cmake, add to path e.g. C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
build-appveyor.bat
- Update vcvarsall.bat location for VS2019 install location (VC\vcvarsall.bat)
- ensure DBOOST_ROOT path matches installed path of DBOOST e.g.  C:/local/boost_1_63_0
```

Download latest nuget.exe and place in path (won't work in system32)

- Ensure nuget source is configured: nuget.exe sources Add -Name nuget.org -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Run build-local.bat

Copy 64-bit release DLLs from bzip2, libexpat nuget pacakges to the same directory as osmium.exe